# Só consigo resolver dependências se usar o '+' nas versões das Bibliotecas

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

**22 Dez 2017**
Erro que deu quando estava com o OfflineWork
[image: Erro que deu quando estava com o OfflineWork]

Após mudar para Online Work
[image: Após mudar para Online Work]

**ORIGINAL:**
Tenho tentado evitar fazer isso desse modo:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

porque é desencorajado o uso do '+', mas o Gradle nunca consegue "resolver as dependencias" se eu usar

```
...v7:26.1.1 ou v7:27.0.2(com os devidos ajustes)
```

ou qualquer outra versão que possa encontrar na web.

Ponho em baixo código completo do build.gradle da App (em 1º) e o build.gradle do projeto (em 2º).

Pergunto: **a)** Como proceder para evitar o '+'?  **b)** Onde posso encontrar as versões (26.x.x, por exemplo) que existem e podem ser compiladas?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26//23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.LearnEnglish"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26//23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    //maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } Este só se usa com Gradle abaixo de 4.1
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4.app.ActivityCompat'//com.android.support:support-compat:+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /*compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'*/
}
```

(projeto:)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Gradle 4.1 and higher include support for Google's Maven repo using
        // the google() method. And you need to include this repo to download
        // Android plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar as bibliotecas de suporte, naquelas que têm relação entre si, tem de utilizar o mesmo número de revisão.

De preferência deve usar a última revisão, que nesta data é a versão 27.0.2.

Em Support Library Packages encontra a listagem de todas as bibliotecas e o respectivo identificador a utilizar no *gradle*.

Pode encontrar a listas e detalhes das revisões mais recentes em [Recent Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-2).

Comment: Certo, então voltei a usar o 27.0.2 em todas as ocorrências e obtive vários erros, mesmo correndo a App online e depois de mudar o 'compileSDKVersion' para 27 (mantive Build tools em 26.0.3): 'Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2' e erro igual para as outra Biblio. No erro refere ainda: 'Could not get Resource https://jcenter... etc'.

Comment: Não sei o que possa dizer mais, talvez ajam outras causas que não as versões.

Comment: 'Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2', Entre no SDK Manager e atualize os itens necessários

Answer (score 0):

Não se recomenda o uso do "+", pode ocasionar em erros, O Android Studio alerta sobre isso nas dependências.

**A)** Como proceder para evitar o '+'?

Use todas as bibliotecas de suporte na mesma versão, Recomendo a 26.1.0 ou parecida(a versão 27.0.2 ta com alguns problemas), 'compileSDKVersion': 26, 'buildToolsVersion':26.1.0 e todas as dependências das bibliotecas de suporte.
    ex:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

**B)** Onde posso encontrar as versões (26.x.x, por exemplo) que existem e podem ser compiladas?

Pessoalmente eu recomendo que olhe no SDK Manager, você vai ver as atualizações necessárias, versões instaladas, etc...

Comment: Parece que o erro de base vem de algo relacionado com os certificados. Atualizei post original com fotos dos erros.

Comment: Tente a versão 26.1.0, Também estou com alguns problemas com a versão 27.0.2, consegui usar no máximo a versão 27.0.0.

Comment: Corrigindo: Consegui usar no máximo a versão 27.0.1(Certifique-se no SDK Manager se a versão usada está instalada)